# Multiple Domains on one Server IP-Adress

Tags: email, ptr-record

i need some help. I would like to host my own Mailserver with two or more domains. But to dont get blocked on outlook.com for example. I need a PTR to every Mail-Domain to get a correct lookup. Can i add multiple pointer to one IP-Adress?

Or is there another way to get it working?

Comment: Name the host ONE thing, then MX all of the domains to that ONE hostname.  So there is only ONE reverse for the host and your problem goes away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can host multiple domains on any mailserver you want. You can assign single or multiple IP addresses to your mailserver, but condition is:

```
 1. your IP address should be clean and reputated which you use for mailing. It should not be black-listed in various RBL's

 2. You should use multiple MX records. It would be good is you use your mx records as mail.abc.xom or smtp.abc.com.

 3. You must add proper SPF records to every domain hosted with you.

 4. DKIM and DMARC records must be updated for every domain hosted.

 5. Rdns and PTR records should be done.

 6. outlook and yahoo have some certain number of range of mails which will be delivered in inbox everyday from every IP address, if you exceed that number of range your mail will be send to spam. So use of multiple IP addresses is required if you want to mail alot at outlook.com on daily basis.
```

You can use one PTR record for multiple domains (you can even use one IP address for PTR), there is no issues with that.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. I understood, except the thing with the PTR. I thought that i can only use one pointer per IP Adress? Did that mean that i have to set a pointer from my ip to every domain i want to send emails with?

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. That means i can set multiple pointers from one ip adress? Is that recommended ?

Comment: On shared hosting servers use of common PTR records is widely used practice. No issues with that as per my knowledge.

Comment: Ok much thanks for your help. Just for my understanding. Now i have to set a PTR from my ReverseLookup to all the Domains i will send mails from?. And add a SPF to all my Domains linking to the mailserver?

Comment: yes exactly mate, also add DKIM records for each domain and For much better reputation to your mail accounts add DMARC records as well. If you you want to wish thank you can upvote and accept my answer by clicking on tick in right front of question.

Answer (score 1):

> Or is there another way to get it working?

Yes. Learn how email works. The host has one domain - that has NOTHING to do with sending out emails for multiple domains. The PTR records remaps the host name. The rest you set up in the domains independent.

Start for example reading

[Does a PTR record prove anything about the sender's email domain?](https://serverfault.com/questions/316210/does-a-ptr-record-prove-anything-about-the-senders-email-domain?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. Did that mean that i only need a mx entry and a SPF record?